# Run specific test from nested suite

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

Consider the following `Suites` which contains couple of nested `Suite`s

```
package example

import org.scalatest.{DoNotDiscover, Suites}
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite

@DoNotDiscover
class NestedSuite1 extends AnyFunSuite  {
  test("A") {}
  test("B") {}
}
@DoNotDiscover
class NestedSuite2 extends AnyFunSuite  {
  test("A") {}
  test("B") {}
}
class ContainingSuite extends Suites(
  new NestedSuite1,
  new NestedSuite2
)
```

How to execute specifically, say, test `B` of `NestedSuite2` via `ContainingSuite`? Note I do not mean

```
Test/runMain org.scalatest.tools.Runner -o -s example.NestedSuite2 -t B
```

because that bypasses `ContainingSuite`. Instead I am after something like

```
Test/runMain org.scalatest.tools.Runner -o -s example.ContainingSuite -i example.NestedSuite2 -t B
```

however that executes both `A` and `B` of `NestedSuite2`

```
sbt:scalatest-seed-3.2.0> Test/runMain org.scalatest.tools.Runner -o -s example.ContainingSuite -i example.NestedSuite2 -t B
[info] running org.scalatest.tools.Runner -o -s example.ContainingSuite -i example.NestedSuite2 -t B
Run starting. Expected test count is: 2
NestedSuite1:
NestedSuite2:
- A
- B
Run completed in 72 milliseconds.
Total number of tests run: 2
Suites: completed 3, aborted 0
Tests: succeeded 2, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
All tests passed.
```

as opposed to expected output similar to

```
NestedSuite1:
NestedSuite2:
- B
Run completed ...
```

[Selecting suites and tests](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.0/org/scalatest/tools/Runner$.html#selectingSuitesAndTests) documents the `-s`, `-i`, and `-t` runner arguments as follows

> `-s` would be used to specify the class ScalaTest can instantiate
> directly, the containing suite that has a public, no-arg constructor,
> and `-i` would be used to select the desired nested suite... The `-t`
> argument allows a test to be selected by its (complete) test name...
> If a `-t` follows either `-s` or `-i`, then it only applies to the
> suite identified.

Note I am using `Test/runMain org.scalatest.tools.Runner` insted of `testOnly` because currently it does [not](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5609) work with `DoNotDiscover` annotations.